# Inject (Initialize)parameter to constructor - Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, autofac

Is there any way to inject a parameter to constructor, which that parameter is currently created in Initialize method on basecontroller?

sample code:

```
public class SSBaseController : Controller
    {
        protected UserProfileClass UserProfile;

        protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(requestContext);
            UserProfile = UserProfileGetter.getProfileFromDB();
        }

    }

    public class SSController:SSBaseController
    {
        private IProcessService processService;
        public SSController(IProcessService _processService)
        {
            processService = _processService;
        }
    }

    public interface IProcessService
    {
        void doStuff();
    }

    public class ProcessService1 : IProcessService
    {
        private UserProfileClass upc;
        private string _name;
        public ProcessService1(UserProfileClass _profileClass)
        {
            upc = _profileClass;
        }

        public void doStuff()
        {
            _name = upc.name;
            upc.name = "xxx";
        }
    }

    public class UserProfileGetter
    {
        public static UserProfileClass getProfileFromDB()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class UserProfileClass

    {
        public string name;
    }
```

Also i want to get rid of initialize, is this possible?
how to register ProcessService with that parameter without being null in SSController?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to integrate ASP.NET MVC and Autofaq. The only two things you have to do then is to register interface implementation and specify the Controller's constructor params. Framework will do all the rest.
See https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration
Here is one more article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/07/16/dependency-injection-with-asp-net-web-api-and-autofac.aspx

Comment: yes i can do that register and stuff easily, just when it takes parameter from an initialized controller, becomes uneasy to understand . I read somewhere to use onactivating?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. It looks like you may pass something like IUserProfileGetter to the controller's constructor and use a property UserProfile that will return _userProfile if it is not null or create it with a help of IUserProfileGetter at the first call.